# MongoDB Java driver 3.2: parallel scan

Tags: java, mongodb

the mongo java driver has an old (and through deprecation of MongoClient.getDB essentially deprecated) method to explicitly perform a parallel scan on a collection.

As far as I can see, this is something along the lines of:

```
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mydb");
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("testCollection");
ParallelScanOptions parallelScanOptions = ParallelScanOptions
            .builder()
            .numCursors(4)
            .batchSize(1000)
            .build();
List<Cursor> cursors = coll.parallelScan(parallelScanOptions);
...
```

The question is: is there a new alternative in driver 3.2 (**without** using the deprecated DB API)?

Answer (score 3):

You can utilise [runCommand()](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/?com/mongodb/client/MongoDatabase.html#runCommand-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.ReadPreference-) to execute [parallelCollectionScan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/parallelCollectionScan/) command directly.

For example:

```
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress());
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("databaseName");
    Document commandResult = database.runCommand(new Document("parallelCollectionScan", "collectionName").append("numCursors", 3));
```

See also [cursor batches](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#cursor-batches)